# If any of these stranger human voice sounds have IPA annotations

Tags: ipa, sound-symbolism

Wondering if the following sounds have written transcriptions / annotations in IPA or any other system:

- Snooring sound (breathing *in*, "hoooonk" is a trill of some sort, then the breathing out "shoo" is already transcribed).
- [Screaming sound](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y8s7c8FkS9M#t=14s). The raspiness in the voice. If the raspy h is transcribed (), maybe this is too.
- Female [grunty/grungy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v6A5lMgdisQ#t=1m58s) (the "whoawhoawhoawhoa" there) singing sound (like [Christina Aguilera does when she says "not" right here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0egNtYs44gE#t=26s), as well as others).
- The "~huh!" sound when you get scared and breath **in** really quickly. It is voiced and a little raspy, deep in the larynx I think.
- Vibratto (singing).
- Cough sound.
- Stick tongue out and rattle, like "nany-nany-nany pthththththt" stick your tongue out at someone.
- "ks ks", the sound when you suck in air in the side of your mouth, stick up your thumbs, (maybe snap), then point at some one, like "yep, you got it, right on."
- The [rain drop sound when flicking the side of your mouth](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8eP_1QmFYq4#t=18s).
- The "monster voice" where you talk so low that it vibrates at the bottom of your throat, seemingly without "voice".
- Whistle.

Other sounds that can be transcribed are "hmmm...", and "psh!", and "hahaha". So wondering if these things can be also. A scream is typically just "ahhhh!" or something like that. But it doesn't include the *raspiness* in the voice, like [Linkin Park's scream](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y8s7c8FkS9M#t=14s). Also, the ["click" sound is transcribed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Click_consonant), which is cool.

Comment: Just [learned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creaky_voice) about the [creaky voice](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ff1JByylQU0).

Answer (score 3):

More extensive than extIPA are the [Voice Quality Symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_Quality_Symbols) which build on them; they still don't meet all of OP's requirements, but there's some amusement to be had with e.g. {И} [electrolaryngeal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrolarynx) phonation or {V!} [harsh voice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harsh_voice) ("Harsh voice includes the use of the ventricular folds (the false vocal cords) to damp the glottis in a way similar to what happens when a person talks while lifting a heavy load, or, if the sound is voiceless, like clearing one's throat.")

Answer (score 1):

There is an extension of IPA called [extIPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensions_to_the_International_Phonetic_Alphabet) for disordered speech that cover a lot of the things you have asked for. Those extensions are also added to the Unicode standard and available on the computer.

Comment: I don't see the scream in there, or whistle, or a few others :/

Comment: A diacritic for "whistled" can be found under the heading "articulation" in the table. Currently, I have no idea on how to translate the scream into more linguistic terms and express it in IPA or extIPA.

Comment: I would call the scream a voiced  I guess. Since it is basically a voiced trill where the h sound comes from. Perhaps ꭙ or ᶍ.

Comment: @LancePollard It is labeled "disordered speech" because it was specifically created for speech pathology. The official IPA, on the other hand, is designed mainly to cover distinctive sounds, i.e. those that are used to distinguish meanings in languages. That is why the IPA has a policy it won't add a symbol unless it's found to be phonemic (distinctive) in a language, except when a simple modification (e.g. "a" → "ã") will do.